# Fix "[Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable" in Python 2.x.x?

Tags: python, sockets, google-cloud-platform

I have two scripts `server.py` & `talk.py`

`server.py` is supposed to listen to connections & consume data from  `talk.py`

It works perfectly on localhost i.e if I run `server.py` & `talk.py` in different terminals on the same machine...

a) `talk.py` asks for a string
b) `server.py` consumes the string from a) & prints it in the terminal that is running `server.py`

Like I said, the scripts run ok on a local machine, Ubuntu.

When I deployed my `server.py` to a GCP VM instance it seems runs fine,
however, why I ran my `talk.py` code in on the local machine to connect to the `server.py` socket via an external web IP address, `talk.py` give the error code

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "talk.py", line 11, in <module>
    s.connect(('35.247.28.0', port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

```py
#server.py

# first of all import the socket library
import socket               

# next create a socket object
s = socket.socket()         
print "Socket successfully created"

# reserve a port on your computer in our
# case it is 12345 but it can be anything
port = 12345               

# Next bind to the port
# we have not typed any ip in the ip field
# instead we have inputted an empty string
# this makes the server listen to requests 
# coming from other computers on the network
s.bind(('', port))        
print "socket binded to %s" %(port)

# put the socket into listening mode
s.listen(5)     
print "socket is listening"           

# a forever loop until we interrupt it or 
# an error occurs
while True:

   # Establish connection with client.
   c, addr = s.accept()     
   print 'Got connection from', addr

   # Get data from client
   """
   try:
       data = c.recv(1024)
   except IOError as e:
       print e
   """

   print data

   if not data:
     break

   # Send back reversed data to client   
   c.sendall(data)


   # send a thank you message to the client. 
   #c.send('\n Thank you for sending message!!!!')

   # Close the connection with the client
   c.close()
```

```py
# talk.py
# first of all import the socket library
import socket               

# next create a socket object
s = socket.socket()         
print "Socket successfully created"

# reserve a port on your computer in our
# case it is 12345 but it can be anything
port = 12345               

# Next bind to the port
# we have not typed any ip in the ip field
# instead we have inputted an empty string
# this makes the server listen to requests 
# coming from other computers on the network
s.bind(('', port))        
print "socket binded to %s" %(port)

# put the socket into listening mode
s.listen(5)     
print "socket is listening"           

# a forever loop until we interrupt it or 
# an error occurs
while True:

   # Establish connection with client.
   c, addr = s.accept()     
   print 'Got connection from', addr

   print data

   if not data:
     break

   # Send back reversed data to client   
   c.sendall(data)


   # send a thank you message to the client. 
   #c.send('\n Thank you for sending message!!!!')

   # Close the connection with the client
   c.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a routing/security issue rather than something with your code. This might help: [How to port forward Google Compute Engine Instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45136282/how-to-port-forward-google-compute-engine-instance)

[edit] Another resource: [How to open a specific port such as 9090 in Google Compute Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065922/how-to-open-a-specific-port-such-as-9090-in-google-compute-engine)